# How to filter columns by first row on Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

The LEFT function doesn't exist on Oracle so I'm a little confused about how to do this. I am needing to only show room numbers that start with 5 (are on the 5th floor) but I do not know how to filter to get those, only how to view the first number for **all** the values in the column.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(room_number,1,1)
FROM Room;
```

I also tried to add `WHERE room_number IN '5'`, but that did not work. I am also needing to return all the column values of rooms on the 5th floor, not just the room_number column.

Comment: You can also use `LIKE`, as in `select * from room where room_number like '5%'`.

Comment: You cannot add `where room_number in '5'`... it should be `where substr(room_number, 1, 1) = '5'`. Or use LIKE as mentioned by the impaler.

Comment: @Isolated my bad, I am still very much a beginner. I kept the substr in the select line when adding the = '5', so it gave me errors, and I couldn't figure out why so I just took it out. But I got it now, thanks!